# ArcPy name raster layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I am using ArcPy to save a TIFF file in a geodatabase file with this code:

```
arcpy.RasterToGeodatabase_conversion(Input_Rasters=r'D:\Projects\GEBCO_2019_Geotiff.tif', Output_Geodatabase=r'D:\Projects\Example.gdb')
```

This will create a layer named `GEBCO_2019_Geotiff`.

What I want is to set by myself the layer name, is there a way?

Comment: If you only have to convert one raster, I would probably use the [`Copy Raster`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-raster.htm) function, which will do the same as the RasterToGeodatabase but will give you control on the name of the output.